# Bootstrap form validation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am validating a form , here if text box is validated successfully a right mark has to appear next to text box and this right mark is a image that I defined in css . Here every thing working fine , my problem is if a text box validated successfully right mark is not appear next to it , insted it appearing in next line. my text box in html page is as follow ,

```
<div class="form-group control-group">
<label for="uln" class="control-label col-xs-4">Teacher Id:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="col-lg-8 controls">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherId"
                    id="teacherId" placeholder="Enter Teacher Id">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**my css file is as follow,**

```
label.valid {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background: url(assets/img/valid.png) center center no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

all validation is working fine I think something I have to change in html code only . can any one help me.

**my jquery function as,**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        $('#create_teacher').validate({
        rules: {
            teacherId: {

            required: true
          },

            teacherName: {
            minlength: 6,
            required: true
          },

            education: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },

            experience: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6

            },

            prevdetails:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 6

            },
            photo:{
                required: true,
                accept: "gif|png|jpg|jpeg|pjpeg"
            },


            email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
          }

        },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            },
            success: function(element) {
                element
                .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
            }

      });
    }); // end document.ready
```

**my form structure is as follow,**

```
<form class="well" id="create_teacher" method="post" action="#">
<div style="height: 850px;">
<div style="width: 104%; margin-top: -20px;">

    <fieldset>
    <legend>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Teacher Information</legend>
</div>
<br> <br>
<div class="form-group control-group">
    <label for="uln" class="control-label col-xs-4">Teacher Id:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="col-lg-8 controls">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherId"
                    id="teacherId" placeholder="Enter Teacher Id">
        </div>
        </div>

</div>
    <div>..</div>
    <div>..</div>
</fieldset> 
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide some more information about _how_ you're validating your form values and at which point the CSS class is applied (or removed). Are you using server side or client side (JS) validation? Pure HTML and CSS code doesn't help much here...

Comment: Works fine for me if i append the "valid" class manuallly to the DIV [JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/hgDsw/)

Comment: @matthias I am using client side validation and validating using Jquery function .

Comment: @matthias I editted my question please check . .

Comment: @alexP I want right mark at the end of text box . .

Comment: Okay, I see - misunderstood your question. Thought it is about functional problems but it's a html (layout) issue indeed. Wait, let's see what I can do...

Comment: @matthias ya please help me . .

Answer (score 0):

With this solution you have to put a DIV with a fixed width around every label and input field.

```
label.valid {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background: url(assets/img/valid.png) center center no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right; /* Add this */
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

<kbd>[JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/hgDsw/2/)</kbd>

Comment: for me in the next line only it is coming right side . .

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add another inline element within your control-group `div`:

```
 <div class="form-group control-group">
     <label for="uln" class="control-label col-xs-4 ">Teacher Id:</label>
     <div class="col-xs-4">
         <div class="col-lg-8 controls">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherId" id="teacherId" placeholder="Enter Teacher Id" />
         </div>
     </div>
     <span class="validation-image valid" />
 </div>
```

So you can handle the appearance of your "validation images" independently from your `label` element (which should appear before the input field if I got you right).

Of course you have to adjust your jQuery calls now to select and manipulate the correct element on success now.

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/g2h6c/6/).

Comment: no now also it is comming next line of text box . . I want just next to text box . .

Comment: Oh wait, now everything is mixed up. You are overriding the space your label claims with the image so this cannot work. I'll correct my answer soon.

Comment: Just updated the whole answer in hope it's getting the right direction now. Question and problems are still a bit unclear to me. Answer depends on how your complete form and elements should be structured and manipulated.

Comment: @matthis no now also it is coming in next line , actually I want right mark if the textbox is validated successfully but here it is present when form is loaded . k I will edit the question form my form structure . . .